# Material Complex UI with Co-ordinate layout + Tab Layout + View pager +recycle view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

Hello I am Developing Application which has some complex UI feature
 , I need some suggestion to built it with the new Material design
 feature.But I am facing some problem .Thanks in adavance.

[image: mockup]

Below Banner Image to viewpager i have build it.but now above banner i am using recycle view .when i click on the item  need to change the whole layout contain according to the top  recylce view click ..eg south indian clicking change whole dishes according to it...then with chineese and so on ..

Please suggest me right way to do it.

Red Marked content design with Material design below is the code..

> activity_menu.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customfontdemo="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/back_icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_filter"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backButton"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/search"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="search Dishes..."
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="12sp">


        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_view"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/filter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/view" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@mipmap/feed_img"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:titleEnabled="false"
                    app:titleMarginTop="15dp">


                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.vdine.customView.MyTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Soup"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            customfontdemo:fontName=" Bill Corporate Narrow Book [TheFontsMaster.com].otf" />

                        <com.vdine.customView.MyTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Worries goes down better with soup"
                            customfontdemo:fontName=" Bill Corporate Narrow Book [TheFontsMaster.com].otf" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/plus"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/red_shed1"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/red" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> MenuActivity.java

```
  public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DishesAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(MenuActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
        arrayList = prepareData();
        adapter = new DishesAdapter(MenuActivity.this, arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(MenuActivity.this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }
        }));

        setupToolbar();

        setupViewPager();

        setupToolbar();
    }

    private ArrayList<String> prepareData() {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("Chineese");
        arrayList.add("South Indian");
        arrayList.add("Mughalai");
        arrayList.add("Local streat");
        return arrayList;

    }


    private void setupViewPager() {
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new TabFragment(), "Soup");
        adapter.addFrag(new TabFragment(), "Rice");
        adapter.addFrag(new TabFragment(), "Breads");
        adapter.addFrag(new TabFragment(), "Curry");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = {"Soups", "Rice", "Breads", "Curry"};
        final int tabCount;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
            super(fm);
            this.tabCount = tabCount;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return InfoFragment.newInstance(position);
            } else {
                return InfoFragment.newInstance(position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put your recycler view inside your main activity, put it inside the fragments shown. depending on the position, appropriate fragment will get called, each with different logic to show proper content inside the recycler view

Answer (score 4):

You can use a TabLayout with a ViewPager and put fragments for each page of the tabs. Each fragment layout can contain your required recyclerview

see:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

This will achieve your purpose and will be easiest to handle

Comment: inside the getItem in the tutorial, you can instantiate different fragments with diff recycler views based on the current position :)

Comment: I have design below UI but I need to change it when user click on the recycleview.

Comment: as i said, when you click a new tab/slide -> the PagerAdapter will change the position and call getItem if the fragment isnt present. here for each position of the tab, put a switch case and call appropriate fragments containing appropriate recyclerviews.

Comment: say if the user clicks on bread, it will trigger the BreadFragment with bread items in your recyclerview and so on.....